# Amazon QuickSight - Adding Custom Visual Content Using boto3 or aws-cli

Tags: boto3, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to add a custom visual content to an existing analysis using either boto3 or aws-cli? If yes, how to do it?